# handle multiple items downloading services. (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-download-manager

to implement a download manager for handling multiple items downloads in my app.

I'm looking to develop an app that can download various file types such as PDFs, images, and videos using URLs. I plan to incorporate a download manager within the app to handle these downloads efficiently. However, I'm seeking guidance on implementing a program that can manage the simultaneous downloading of multiple items and display the progress of these downloads within the app. How can I effectively manage this task?

Comment: Your only question is so vague it's unanswerable. Check
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question and check
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager to see if it helps with your task.

Comment: `to implement a download manager for handling multiple items downloads in my app.` Sorry that is no sentence. You cannot start a post like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

- Use a wrapper around Aria2 like [this one](https://github.com/Ricardo-Evans/Aria2).
- Write a library completely from scratch. [Here's](https://github.com/lingochamp/FileDownloader) an example project for android. You might find better examples if you Google more.